# What is the correct way to use Devise gem authentication with Mobile (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, titanium-mobile

I am using Devise gem for web authentication in my Application.

Now i am about to write a mobile app for my Application which includes Sign in / Sign up process.

What is the correct way i should use to sign in a user and authenticate each call made by the user from the mobile app?

Which of the below strategy is correct? (i am not sure which method to follow to be more secure)

[image]

**Note : You can view the above image in https://i.stack.imgur.com/I13uT.png (will be more clear)**

**FYI : I am using Titanium to develop mobile app and my backend server runs Rails app**

Comment: I just want to double check, but this is a Rails application acting as your server, right?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to put together an answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Model #1 isn't secure, you aren't passing any sort of authentication on subsequent requests to validate that the user is still who they say they are.

What I'm presuming you really want to know is, what's the best way to verify the user is who they say they are, after logging in. I've answered this previously, [Exposing Rails/Devise Authentication to iOS application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8836238/exposing-rails-devise-authentication-to-ios-application/8840086#8840086) and the same answer applies here.

Using token authentication in Devise will match model #2, and is also the most secure since you exchange the username/password for a token rather than having to store their username and password and reuse it with every request.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how #1 is secure at all since none of the subsequent requests are signed in any way. If someone knew the file structure of your app they could just access it that way, right?

With Devise, you can set an attribute on your `User` model to allow users to be authenticated via token:

```rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :token_authenticatable
  # there are other details and options on this, but this is the relevant piece
end
```

On each controller you can also verify that the user is authenticated by including `before_filter :authenticate_user!` at the beginning:

```rb
class PostsController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
end
```

When making requests from the mobile app, include the auth_token in the request so that the Rails app can authenticate before responding.

Beyond authentication, you may also be interested in something like [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) to handle authorization as well.

Comment: Will the authtoken gets refreshed for each call? or will it be static?

Comment: By default I think the token is static, however as of devise 2.1 you can add a line to devise's config to reset the token when the session times out. `config.expire_auth_token_on_timeout = true` https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/commit/b1b6e53d6fa74a19286c2d00672fbd3bcf86b68b

Comment: thanks, balanv. I'm working on a Rails API for an iOS developer and have struggled in a few places so looking to build some karma haha